# How to insert current day, month and year in database

Tags: c#

I want the current `day`, `month` and `year` in inserted in my database.
The `format` needs to be: `YYYY-MM-DD`. How to do this? I use de datatype 'date' in my table. It has to be the same value as what it is in the database. I use C#.

Now I get the error: 'Error converting data type nvarchar to date'

Code:

```
string datenow = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

I use a Stored Procedure for adding the date value (and some other things):

```
conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddContentment", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@question", SqlDbType.VarChar, 220);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeid", Variabels.employeeid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@score", SqlDbType.Char).Value = score;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBxComment.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = datenow;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Didn't you try `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");` ?

Comment: [RTFM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: I just edited my question, I hope you have a answer to this as well.

Comment: Don't store a *string*, store the *data*. Which will be in some date(time) data type which doesn't *have* a format. Leave formatting concerns to *input validation* and to *output presentation*. You'll get formatting issues when you inappropriately allow conversions between the proper data types and strings.

Comment: @fubo just did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = datenow;
```

with

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

since

> Now I get the error: 'Error converting data type nvarchar to date'

says that you've tried to insert a string but the procedure expects a date.
If you want to skip the time part, you can use `DateTime.Now.Date` or `DateTime.Today`

Answer (score 1):

> The format needs to be: YYYY-MM-DD

Noooooooo!!

A date here should be stored as a typed value - perhaps of type `date` (no time part) or `datetime`. Now; here's the thing: a date value *has no format*. It is essentially just a number. It is simply incorrect to even ask the question "what (text) format is my date stored as", in the same way that it would be incorrect to ask what (text) format an `int` is stored as. Quite simply: *it isn't*, because it isn't text.

If you are storing dates (or integers) as text (in some kind of `[n][var]char(...)` column, for example): *that is a problem*, and can lead to huge confusions, problems, and inefficiencies - including problems with sorting, filtering, and i18n/l10n problems.

Instead: declare the column as `date` or `datetime`, and use a typed value from .NET to populate it, for example passing down a SQL parameter with a value that is a .NET `DateTime`. The ADO.NET `SqlClient` layer knows how to connect those things, and all the right magic will happen.

Only when you are *actually displaying a date in some way* does it become correct to ask about the format. It is, for example, perfectly correct to ask:

> I have a `DateTime` value that I got from the database; what display format should I use in my web-page to display it?

The important point being : it is now a *display* concern, not a *storage* concern.